Why does my final video lose one of the previous audio tracks?
Ok. I have to say that I’ve been trying to solve this problem for a little over 6 hours, but I just can’t figure it out. If anyone has an idea of what could be happening, I’d appreciate it in advance. Well, let’s go.
I recorded a very simple video using OBS. I recorded this video with two separate audio channels: one capturing my microphone and the other capturing the PC’s audio.

So, of course, when I created the sequence and brought the video into Premiere, it split the audio tracks according to each channel recorded in OBS. So far, so good.
My goal is to compile a video in .mp4 format where both audios can be heard simultaneously, without me having to switch between audio tracks. I recorded it this way because it makes it easier to increase or decrease the volume of the separate audio tracks.
But what’s happening is that when I export the file through Premiere, the audio track corresponding to the PC audio disappears, it’s removed. I can only hear my voice. Even when I go to the timeline and press the spacebar, both audios play normally (on the timeline, I can hear both audios, as can be seen in the equalizer in the previous photo). I’m sending pictures of how the channels are distributed for each of the tracks:

Here are the settings for the sequence where the video is:

And here are the export settings:

Now, what am I doing wrong? Why does the second track, the music track, disappear when I export the final file? And by the way, my voice also loses some quality and ends up getting louder, clipping a bit.

EDIT
I forgot to also show you my sequence audio channels:


If the music was recorded in mono to both left and right channels, but one side ended up phase reversed, this could explain it: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27926/premiere-pro-audio-muffled-and-distorted-on-export/32275#32275

@tomh Hey, thanks for the answer. There's no Channel Mixer effect on my Premiere Pro, though. Man, I really thought it would be a good idea to record a video with 2 channels, just uploading it to Premiere and work with both audio. What's really upsetting is that in the timeline, when I press play, it works FINE. Then, export ruins it. Really don't know what to do :(

Can you put the files online somewhere?

I tried to replicate this on a Mac - (don't have a PC). I was able to export separate mic and screen captured audio from OBS into Premiere, using a "fragmented .mov" output file. MKV format isn't recognised by Premiere on the mac. When I exported to mp4, both the mic and the Screen Capture audio were mixed correctly.  Sorry can't be more help - maybe try the OBS forums?
